# How to conditionally remove duplicates from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

Consider the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                   'B' : ['a','b','c','c','d','d','e','f','g'],
                   'Col_1' :[np.NaN, 'A','A', np.NaN, 'B', np.NaN, 'B', np.NaN, np.NaN],
                   'Col_2' :[2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5]})
df
Out[92]: 
    A  B Col_1  Col_2
 0  1  a   NaN      2
 1  2  b     A      2
 2  3  c     A      3
 3  3  c   NaN      3
 4  4  d     B      3
 5  4  d   NaN      3
 6  5  e     B      4
 7  6  f   NaN      4
 8  7  g   NaN      5
```

I want to remove all rows which are duplicates with regards to column `'A' 'B'`. I want to remove the entry which has a `NaN` entry (I know that for all dulicates there will be a `NaN` and a not-`NaN` entry). The end results should look like this

```
    A  B Col_1  Col_2
 0  1  a   NaN      2
 1  2  b     A      2
 2  3  c     A      3
 4  4  d     B      3
 6  5  e     B      4
 7  6  f   NaN      4
 8  7  g   NaN      5
```

All efficient, one-liners are most welcome

Comment: In the down voter's defence, you could have chosen an example where simply `df.drop_duplicates` gave you the answer you did not want.

Comment: yes yes. I accept the downvote :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an alternative:

```
df[~((df[['A', 'B']].duplicated(keep=False)) & (df.isnull().any(axis=1)))]
#    A  B Col_1  Col_2
# 0  1  a   NaN      2
# 1  2  b     A      2
# 2  3  c     A      3
# 4  4  d     B      3
# 6  5  e     B      4
# 7  6  f   NaN      4
# 8  7  g   NaN      5
```

This uses the bitwise "not" operator `~` to negate rows that meet the joint condition of being a duplicate row (the argument `keep=False` causes the method to evaluate to True for all non-unique rows) and containing at least one null value. So where the expression `df[['A', 'B']].duplicated(keep=False)` returns this Series:

```
# 0    False
# 1    False
# 2     True
# 3     True
# 4     True
# 5     True
# 6    False
# 7    False
# 8    False
```

...and the expression `df.isnull().any(axis=1)` returns this Series:

```
# 0     True
# 1    False
# 2    False
# 3     True
# 4    False
# 5     True
# 6    False
# 7     True
# 8     True
```

... we wrap both in parentheses (required by Pandas syntax whenever using multiple expressions in indexing operations), and then wrap them in parentheses *again* so that we can negate the entire expression (i.e. `~( ... )`), like so:

```
~((df[['A','B']].duplicated(keep=False)) & (df.isnull().any(axis=1))) & (df['Col_2'] != 5)

# 0     True
# 1     True
# 2     True
# 3    False
# 4     True
# 5    False
# 6     True
# 7     True
# 8    False
```

You can build more complex conditions with further use of the logical operators `&` and `|` (the "or" operator). As with SQL, group your conditions as necessary with additional parentheses; for instance, filter based on the logic "both *condition X* AND *condition Y* are true, or *condition Z* is true" with `df[ ( (X) & (Y) ) | (Z) ]`.

Comment: I think you need to pass `keep=False` to `duplicated` for this to work.

Comment: @ayhan I was just thinking the same thing :)

Comment: Hi. Would this work if there was some other value than `NaN` we wanted to get rid of? Could we just fix the argument after `&`?

Comment: @mortysporty yes, that's basically right -- I should caveat, though, that depending on how you're testing for that value, it's probably easiest if you un-group the conditions (i.e. remove the outer parentheses) so that you can do something like `~(df.duplicated) & (df.Col_2 != 5)`. If you directly substitute `df.Col_2 != 5` into the one-liner above, it will be negated (i.e. True becomes False and vice-versa) because of the way the two current conditions are grouped inside `~( ... )`.

Answer (score 9):

If the goal is to only drop the `NaN` duplicates, a slightly more involved solution is needed.

First, sort on `A`, `B`, and `Col_1`, so `NaN`s are moved to the bottom for each group. Then call `df.drop_duplicates` with `keep=first`:

```
out = df.sort_values(['A', 'B', 'Col_1']).drop_duplicates(['A', 'B'], keep='first')
print(out)

   A  B Col_1  Col_2
0  1  a   NaN      2
1  2  b     A      2
2  3  c     A      3
4  4  d     B      3
6  5  e     B      4
7  6  f   NaN      4
8  7  g   NaN      5
```

Comment: Maybe :) but does this guarantee that the non-`NaN` values of `Col_1` are the rows that are kept?

Comment: @mortysporty Edited.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can just using `first()`, by using the first , will give back the first `notnull` value, so the order of original input does not really matter.

```
df.groupby(['A','B']).first()

Out[180]: 
    Col_1  Col_2
A B             
1 a   NaN      2
2 b     A      2
3 c     A      3
4 d     B      3
5 e     B      4
6 f   NaN      4
7 g   NaN      5
```