# How to Conditionally Remove Duplicates from Pandas DataFrame with a List

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a `df`, and want to remove all duplicates on `ID`.

```
       Name     Symbol         ID
0   ZOO INC     Remove  88579Y101
1   Zoo Inc        ZZZ  88579Y101
2     A Inc        AAA  90138A103
3     a inc.    Remove  90138A103
4    2U Inc       TWUO  90214J101
5      Keep     Remove  111111111
```

But I only want to remove the duplicate rows where `Symbol == 'Remove'`. The output should look like:

```
       Name     Symbol         ID
0   Zoo Inc        ZZZ  88579Y101
1     A Inc        AAA  90138A103
2    2U Inc       TWUO  90214J101
3      Keep     Remove  111111111
```

I can't use `result_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'], keep='first')` (or `keep='last'`) because the dataset doesn't have a specific pattern. And sorting alphabetically first won't help either.

And while I know I can replace all `Remove` with `NaN`, and then use the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45907133/how-to-conditionally-remove-duplicates-from-a-pandas-dataframe), I am looking for an alternate solution because I may eventually need to pass a list of strings.

Does Pandas support anything like: `result_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'], keep=(df['Symbol'] != 'Remove'))`?

Comment: `df[~df['Symbol'].eq('Remove')]`?

Comment: But doesn't that remove all rows where `Symbol == 'Remove`? I only want to remove those that are duplicates on `ID`. I will update the question to make this clearer.

Comment: That doesn't reflect on your sample data. But then again, jezrael's answer would already covers it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep=False` for all dupes and chain with compare for `Remove`, chain together by `|` for bitwise `OR` and invert mask by `~`:

```
m1 = df['ID'].duplicated(keep=False)
m2 = (df['Symbol'] == 'Remove')

df = df[~(m1 & m2)]

print (df)
      Name Symbol         ID
1  Zoo Inc    ZZZ  88579Y101
2    A Inc    AAA  90138A103
4   2U Inc   TWUO  90214J101
5     Keep     Remove  111111111
```

Comment: You may want to also show ID 111111111 in your output (which is the tricky part, but your technique produces this so my upvote).